# eth0 down, how to bring it up?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

My Laptop has always worked well, but since a couple of days I am experiencing troubles with the Ethernet port of my laptop (HP Pavilion 15 with **Ubuntu 15.10**).  **It looks like the cable is not even connected** (when it connects it used to show a light on the port). I tried changing cable, wall socket, checking if there was some dust in the socket but nothing revealed useful. The **interface eth0 results down**, I searched extensively on the internet, but I am not able to make it work again.
I tried:

```
oliver@oliver-PC:~$ sudo ifup eth0
ifup: interface eth0 already configured
-----------------
oliver@oliver-PC:~$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate 
down
------
oliver@oliver-PC:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: no
--------------------
oliver@oliver-PC:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a4:5d:36:7b:39:0c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  
-----------
oliver@oliver-PC:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

but since I am not expert I don't know what it should be and what the output mean.

**Anybody have any idea of what I could try to make it work again?**

I hope I have been able to supply enough information. If anybody needs some output, I can post it here, this is all I have been able to think it could be useful

PS: On the same machine I also have Windows 8.1 installed, but the interface seems to not work even there. Also windows recognize it but the cable is still not recognized. All this happened while I was on ubuntu by the way (without upgrading or doing anything. I went to sleep and the morning after eth0 was down)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work even on Win, I fear this is an HW issue. Try to boot a live CD and check if it works

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I disagree: **This is extremely probably a HW problem** *is an answer...*